# Addressing Files in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This question sounds simple, but it's a serious problem for me
I want to transfer my Laravel project from localhost to my host
At the bootstrap/cache/config.php , the files are addressed
But I do not know how to change this address.

The part of bootstrap/cache/config.php that I want to change:

```
    array (
      'address' => 'hello@example.com',
      'name' => 'Example',
    ),
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'username' => 'myemail',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'markdown' => 
    array (
      'theme' => 'default',
      'paths' => 
      array (
        0 => 'C:\\wamp\\www\\Smm\\laravel\\resources\\views/vendor/mail',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

It should be noted that I have my own project folders
(resources,storage,vendor, ...) I keep myself in the 'reset' folder.
And the reset folder is in the root.

Comment: The default value is `'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),`. You can change it in `config/session.php`.

Comment: `bootstrap/cache/config.php` is automatically generated using `php artisan config:cache` so you should run that on your server as well. Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration#configuration-caching)

Comment: I don't have access to ssh

Comment: What can I do for       `0 => 'C:\\wamp\\www\\Smm\\laravel\\resources\\views',`

Comment: Ok, that entry comes from somewhere, the file you're mentioning is only a cache the real value is in `config/session.php` so you should (a) change that to be an environment variable (b) make sure you upload a correct .env file to the server and (c) don't upload the cache/config.php at all or generate it using the server's .env file. Last (but not least) **get yourself decent hosting which allows ssh connections**

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: You could use a relative path probably.

Comment: How? I tested some relative path but not worked

Answer (score 1):

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-storage-path